# How to add a function in Nuxt js

Tags: nuxt.js

I simply want to add function into my vue.

I have tried, without success, I don't understand how to do that in Nuxt.js ?

**HTML**

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="255" id="mytext" onkeyup="write()" placeholder="Write something ..."/>
<div id="fontface1"></div>
<div id="fontface2"></div>
```

**Vanilla JS**

```js
function write() {
  document.getElementById("fontface1").innerHtml = 
  document.getElementById("mytext").value;
  document.getElementById("fontface2").innerHtml = 
  document.getElementById("mytext").value;
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly, if you want to get the value in input you should use v-model

Comment: You should look into https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers.
Nuxt is basically Vue 2 now. Also you should provide a more in depth description of your problem. So we can find better answers for you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming HTML code is a part of VUE2/Nuxt template:

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="255" id="mytext" v-on:keyup="write" placeholder="Write something ..."/>
```

As you can see I used `v-on:keyup="write"` but you can also use shorthands like `@keyup="write"`

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    write: function () {
      console.log('key up')
    }
  }
}
```

Consider looking into https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html and https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers for more information how to handle events in VUE/Nuxt.

---

But assuming your HTML code is not an part of the VUE template. You have to create event Listener on the HTML element.

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="255" id="mytext" placeholder="Write something ..."/>
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return{
      input: null,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.input = document.getElementById("mytext");
    //Check if input exists and create event listener
    if(this.input)  this.input.addEventListener('keyup', this.handleKeyUp);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    //To avoid memory leak remove event listener if input exists before leaving view/component
    if(this.input)  this.input.removeEventListener('keyup', this.handleKeyUp);
  },
  methods: {
    handleKeyUp(event){
      console.log('keyUp', event)
    }
  }
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/xoahkegv/

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to call a function in Nuxt upon keypress.

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="255" id="mytext" @keyup="write" placeholder="Write something ..."/>
```

```html
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    write() {
      console.log('writting here')
      // I do not show the equivalent of the vanillaJS code because this is not the way to go
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

---

**However** as stated by @omer, you should not use any querySelector like in VanillaJS since VueJS is declarative (vanillaJS is imperative). You should take the time to read the VueJS documentation and use **state** as it's awaited by the framework you're currently using rather than fiddling with selecting the elements and dealing with them *manually*.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/